# how do I transform a date using msxsl:format-date()

Tags: xslt-1.0

Every time I attempt to transform a date using `msxsl:format-date(@testDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy')`
I get an empty string...

However, If I just call `<xsl:value-of select="AcessDate"/>` then I do indeed get a date...  What am I missing?  It's not like I am not navigating to the right element via X-PATH?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:for-each select="//SelectFairWarningInformationResult">
  <!--<xsl:variable name="AccessDate" select="AcessDate"/>-->
  <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date(@test, 'MM-dd-yyyy')"/> | <xsl:value-of select="Acess"/> | <xsl:value-of select="PatName"/> | <xsl:value-of select="PatFName"/> | <xsl:value-of select="PatID"/> | <xsl:value-of select="UID"/> | <xsl:value-of select="ULName"/> | <xsl:value-of select="UFName"/>  | View Record&#10;
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You need to tell us which XSLT processor you use or want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime then to format a date value you can and should use the [format-date function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date) that XSLT 2.0 defines.

You have not shown us which URI the prefix `msxsl` is bound to in your code but I assume you are trying to use a proprietary extension function that the Microsoft XSLT 1.0 processor MSXML 6 supports. I would not expect other XSLT vendors to support that function, in particular XSLT 2.0 processors, as the XSLT 2.0 standard has support for the schema `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` data types and has corresponding formatting functions as well.

Using XSLT 2.0 I think you can use `format-date(@test, "[M01]-[D01]-[Y0001]")`. Take that as an example you might need to tune, I am afraid I don't know details of what `msxsl:format-date` does.

Comment: Ill give you a point for attempting.  But yes, it is the proprietary Microsoft namespace...  Ill update my question more to reflect that.

Comment: Are you actually using a Microsoft XSLT processor like MSXML 6 supporting that extension function? I tested http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013041601.xml respectively the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013041601.xsl with IE 10 which uses MSXML 6 and the dates are formatted (as e.g. `04-15-2013`). Your question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 and Microsoft does not have an XSLT 2.0 processor. And for the existing ones I am not sure they support that function.

Comment: I also tested with Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform in .NET, it seems to support that function too.

Comment: You know, I am not certain.  I could have sworn it was 2.0.  But I will need to double check.